# My Livecode Android app crashes unless have android version 6...why?

Tags: android, livecode

I am not sure why but there is a "native crash" if an older version than 6 tried to open my app. Why would this be?

Here is a crash report from a S5 Active:

```
    Build fingerprint: 'samsung/klteattactive/klteattactive:5.0/LRX21T/G870AUCU2BOF3:user/release-keys'
Revision: '2'
ABI: 'arm'
pid: 21562, tid: 21562, name: sidy.rescueapet  >>> com.cassidy.rescueapet <<<
signal 4 (SIGILL), code 1 (ILL_ILLOPC), fault addr 0x97010
    r0 00000000  r1 b6f6ec07  r2 00097011  r3 b6f7382c
    r4 00097010  r5 b6f6ec07  r6 af701504  r7 b6f6ed08
    r8 00000019  r9 b6f7382c  sl 00000001  fp 00c52000
    ip 00000007  sp bea141f0  lr b6f66a8f  pc 00097010  cpsr 80070010

backtrace:
    #00 pc 0008f010  /data/app/com.cassidy.rescueapet-2/lib/arm/librevandroid.so
```

If other information would be helpful please let me know, thank you!

Comment: Which is the minSdkVersion you are setting?

Comment: @Fer In Google Developer I have not excluded any devices. Is minSdkVersion a setting in LiveCode?

Comment: Probably it is a project configuration option. Is it possible that during the project creation you set 6.0 as minimum version? In this case I suppose you can change it in the project configuration.

Comment: @Fer In standalone application settings there is "Minimum Android Version" which is set to "Gingerbread - 2.3.3."